# For a RICHEDIT control, what is a character class and what are valid values?

Tags: winapi, richedit

From the documentation of [EDITWORDBREAKPROCA callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-editwordbreakproca):

> ## [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-editwordbreakproca#parameters)
>
> `code`
>
> Type: **int**
>
> The action to be taken by the callback function. This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> #### WB_CLASSIFY
>
> Retrieves the character class and word break flags of the character at the specified position. This value is for use with rich edit controls.
>
> ## [Return Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nc-winuser-editwordbreakproca#return-value)
>
> Type: **int**
>
> ... If the *code* parameter specifies **WB_CLASSIFY**, the return value is the character class and word break flags of the character at the specified position. ...

From the documentation of [EM_FINDWORDBREAK message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-findwordbreak):

> ## [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-findwordbreak#parameters)
>
> *wParam*
>
> Specifies the find operation. This parameter can be one of the following values.
>
> #### WB_CLASSIFY
>
> Returns the character class and word-break flags of the character at the specified position.
>
> ## [Return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-findwordbreak#return-value)
>
> The message returns a value based on the *wParam* parameter.
>
> #### WB_CLASSIFY
>
> Returns the character class and word-break flags of the character at the specified position.

My question is what is a character class in this context and what are valid values?  What values are for the flags?  I can't find any information on this anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I'm just blind.  There's a link that could be found at the bottom of the page:

> ## [EM_FINDWORDBREAK message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-findwordbreak)
>
> ...
>
> ### [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-findwordbreak#remarks)
>
> If wParam is WB_LEFT and WB_RIGHT, the word-break procedure finds word breaks only after delimiters. This matches the functionality of an edit control. If wParam is WB_MOVEWORDLEFT or WB_MOVEWORDRIGHT, the word-break procedure also compares character classes and word-break flags.
>
> For information about character classes and word-break flags, see [Word and Line Breaks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/using-rich-edit-controls).

As you can see, on the last line, there is a link to the information to another page that then goes to another which says:

> ## [How to Use Word and Line Break Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-word-and-line-break-information)
>
> ### [Instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-word-and-line-break-information#instructions)
>
> #### [Use Word and Line Break Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-word-and-line-break-information#use-word-and-line-break-information)
>
> ...
>
> Word-break procedures for rich edit controls also group characters into character classes, each identified by a value in the range 0x00 through 0x0F. Breaks occur either after delimiters or between characters of different classes. Thus, a word-break procedure with different classes for alphanumeric and punctuation characters would find two word breaks in the string "Win.doc" (before and after the period).
>
> A character's class can be combined with zero or more word-break flags to form an 8-bit value. When performing word-wrap operations, a rich edit control uses word-break flags to determine where it can break lines. Rich Edit uses the following word-break flags.
>
> ```
> Flag            Description
>
> WBF_BREAKAFTER  Lines may be broken after the character.
>
> WBF_BREAKLINE   The character is a delimiter. Delimiters mark the ends
>                 of words. Lines may be broken after delimiters.
>
> WBF_ISWHITE     The character is a white-space character. Trailing
>                 white-space characters are not included in the length
>                 of a line when wrapping.
> ```
>
> The WBF_BREAKAFTER value is used to allow wrapping after a character that does not mark the end of a word, such as a hyphen.

It's because of the second level of indirection that I didn't see it right away.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/use-word-and-line-break-information):

> Word-break procedures for rich edit controls also **group characters into character classes, each identified by a value in the range 0x00 through 0x0F**. Breaks occur either after delimiters or between characters of different classes. Thus, a word-break procedure with different classes for alphanumeric and punctuation characters would find two word breaks in the string "Win.doc" (before and after the period).
>
> A character's class can be combined with zero or more word-break flags to form an 8-bit value. When performing word-wrap operations, a rich edit control uses word-break flags to determine where it can break lines. Rich Edit uses the following word-break flags
>
> - `WBF_BREAKAFTER` Lines may be broken after the character.
> - `WBF_BREAKLINE` The character is a delimiter. Delimiters mark the ends of words. Lines may be broken after delimiters.
> - `WBF_ISWHITE` The character is a white-space character. Trailing white-space characters are not included in the length of a line when wrapping.
>
> The `WBF_BREAKAFTER` value is used to allow wrapping after a character that does not mark the end of a word, such as a hyphen.

Which is not super helpful. You could perhaps invent your own class enum but I would suggest using [`GetStringTypeW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-getstringtypew).

I have seen .NET example code calling `Char.​Get​Unicode​Category` but it seems to me like that will return values outside the documented range.